# How can I verify sstate-mirror usage?

Tags: yocto

I want to verify that my sstate mirror is used properly. I added it to the `SSTATE_MIRRORS`  variable. How can I check how much is re-used from that sstate-mirror

Comment: Kindly refer to the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) question on SO. Kindly show some efforts from your side too.

Comment: My effort were answering my own question and sharing with people ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When inherited globally, prints statistics at the end of the build on sstate re-use. Add to your local.conf:

```
USER_CLASSES += "buildstats buildstats-summary"
```

If sstate works in general, you can see something like:

```
NOTE: Preparing runqueue
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Running setscene task 118 of 155 (virtual:native:/home/lulianhao/poky-build/edwin/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/pseudo/pseudo_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot_setscene)
NOTE: Running setscene task 119 of 155 (/home/lulianhao/poky-build/edwin/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/quilt/quilt-native_0.48.bb:do_populate_sysroot_setscene)
```

You also should see how much packages are re-used from the sstate mirror

```
Checking sstate mirror object availability: 100% |##########################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:47
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 5119 tasks of which 5104 didn't need to be rerun and all succeeded.
NOTE: Writing buildhistory
NOTE: Build completion summary:
NOTE:   do_populate_sysroot: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 1 scratch)
NOTE:   do_package_qa: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 1 scratch)
NOTE:   do_package: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 1 scratch)
NOTE:   do_packagedata: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 1 scratch)
NOTE:   do_package_write_rpm: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 1 scratch)
NOTE:   do_populate_lic: 0.0% sstate reuse(0 setscene, 1 scratch)
```

https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/classes.html#buildstats